# Several beans implementating the same interface

Tags: spring, spring-el, spring-rabbit

The exact usage is like this:

```
    @Slf4j
public class Client<E, Key> {
    @Getter @NonNull private final UpdateListener<E, Key> updateListener;
    @NonNull private final SubscriptionFactory subscriptionFactory;
    @NonNull private final Map<Key, Instant> updatedRegistry = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Client(UpdateListener<E, Key> updateListener,
                  SubscriptionFactory subscriptionFactory) {
        this.updateListener = updateListener;
        this.subscriptionFactory = subscriptionFactory;
        this.subscriptionFactory.registerSnapshotClient(updateListener);
        log.info("Created new snapshot client for entity key [{}], update type [{}] and component qualifier [{}]",
            updateListener.getEntityKey(),
            updateListener.getOptionalChangeType(),
            updateListener.getComponentQualifier());
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = {"#{@queueNameCreator.createUpdateQueueName(snapshotClient.getUpdateListener())}",
                                "#{@queueNameCreator.createSnapshotQueueName(snapshotClient.getUpdateListener())}"})
    public void handleMessage(Message<E> rawUpdate, @Header("last_updated") Instant newUpdatedTime) {
        ...//more code
    }
}
```

Each 'Client' instance has its own bean id to not clash with each other.

How can I call get the exact updateListener of this object using SpEl?

## Update

After using programattical approach and registering method I get the following exception:

```
    Apr 28, 2015 3:22:47 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler handleError
WARNING: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.everymatrix.om2020.messaging.model.SnapshotClient.handleMessage(org.springframework.messaging.Message<E>,java.time.Instant)' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1241)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument [0] [type=org.springframework.messaging.Message]
```

## Update

Done, you need to do the following to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public static class OmbeRabbitListenerConfigurer implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {
    @Autowired ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired SnapshotClientQueueNamesCreator snapshotClientQueueNamesCreator;
    @Autowired RabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory;
    @Autowired MessageConverter messageConverter;

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        final Collection<SnapshotClient> snapshotClients = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SnapshotClient.class).values();
        System.out.println(snapshotClients);

        snapshotClients.stream().forEach(bean -> {
            final String snapshotQueueName = snapshotClientQueueNamesCreator.createSnapshotQueueName(bean.getUpdateListener());
            final String updateQueueName = snapshotClientQueueNamesCreator.createUpdateQueueName(bean.getUpdateListener());

            Method method = Stream.of(bean.getClass().getMethods()).filter(x -> x.getName().equals("handleMessage")).findAny().get();

            MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint = new MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint();

            final DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
            messageHandlerMethodFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

            endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory);

            endpoint.setBean(bean);
            endpoint.setMethod(method);

            endpoint.setId(snapshotQueueName + ":" + updateQueueName + UUID.randomUUID());
            endpoint.setQueueNames(snapshotQueueName, updateQueueName);
            endpoint.setExclusive(false);

            registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint, rabbitListenerContainerFactory);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If `e` is a bean from class `E`, simply call `e.a.doSomething();`

Comment: Update question a bit, but what should I do if there are several instances of E with different implementations of C?

Comment: When you call `e.c.doSomething();` each instance of `E` will use its own `C`  implementation. That's what DI is made for.

Comment: You mean it knows the exact instance that will be injected at the time of SpEL evaluation?

Comment: Also if I have custom bean ids for each of E instance, will it still work?

Comment: Oups, what to you mean by *the exact instance that will be injected at the time of SpEL evaluation*  ? Please give more details notably how and where you use SpEL evaluation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76415/discussion-between-serge-ballesta-and-eddie-jamsession).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear - you seem to be mixing runtime and initialization time concepts.

For example, `"#{@queueNameCreator.createUpdateQueueName(e.c.doSomething())}"` is evaluated once during initialization - it's not clear from this expression what `e` is, or where it comes from.

But, you seem to be passing in an `E` in the payload of message: `Message<E> rawUpdate`. This message came from the queue and therefore can't influence the queue name.

Perhaps if you can explain what you are trying to do rather than how you have attempted to do it, I can update this "answer" with possible solutions.

**EDIT**:

If you mean you want to reference some field in the current (listener) bean in your SpEL then it can't be done directly.

**EDIT2**:

I can't think of any way to get a reference to the current bean in the SpEL expression - it has to be a constant; that's just the way annotations work in Java; they are tied to the class, not the instance.

I think to do what you want, you would need to revert to using [programmatic endpoint registration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven-registration). However, you'd need to wire in a `MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint` (rather than the `SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint`) to get the benefits of the annotation you are looking for (`@Header` etc).

We don't really cover it in the documentation; it's a little advanced, but essentially, you need to inject the bean and `Method` (for the listener), and a `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory`.

Comment: I need to determine the queue names based on the polimorphicall object that is being passed in the constructor of listener object, this is the main point.

Comment: The main problem is an ability to define the queue names at initialization time using configurable way, it can be anything, but I should have ability to control it.

Comment: But your question does not show the object "being passed into the listener" - show more of your listener class. Plus remove the confusion of having an E as the payload (Vs. this 'E' object that's passed in).

Comment: Ok, so maybe SpEl is not right here for me, can I bind this listener to queue without annotation, but still have the possiblity to extract headers using @Header?